# Getting Force Close when starting Android Service (as Server Socket)

Tags: java, android

I have an application with many activities, and "behind" the application I want a server socket always running, listening and serving data on request.

So I've created a service, but maybe I'm not understanding how it works because I'm having some problems. Let's see my service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";  
    @Override   
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {  
        return null;    
    }       
    @Override   
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("STATUS", "onCreate service");    

        try {


            // create socket
            ServerSocket servsock;
            servsock = new ServerSocket(50000);
            Log.v("STATUS","SERVER SOCKET CREATED at="+50000);


while (true) {
                Log.v("status","Waiting..."); 

                Socket sc = servsock.accept();
                Log.v("status","Accepted connection : " + sc);

                ObjectOutputStream os =  new ObjectOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
                .........
                sc.close();

            }

.............
```

In my app the first screen appearing it's a login screen, and I want the service to start imediatelly after the login (on creation of the "logged in" activity)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
........
```

Problem is, when the activity starts I get a Force Close above a black screen (interesting because the startService is after the setContentView) - although I can see through the Logcat that the service (and the server socket) was executed.

The activity manager gives me the following information:

> 01-10 17:55:43.706: E/ActivityManager(2490): ANR in
>   com.sapo.android.obesidade 01-10 17:55:43.706:
>   E/ActivityManager(2490): Reason: Executing service
>   com.sapo.android.obesidade/.MyService 01-10 17:55:43.706:
>   E/ActivityManager(2490): Load: 1.24 / 1.13 / 1.1 01-10 17:55:43.706:
>   E/ActivityManager(2490): CPU usage from 43658ms to 10ms ago: 01-10
>   17:55:43.706: E/ActivityManager(2490):   system_server: 6% = 3% user +
>   3% kernel / faults: 7590 minor 01-10 17:55:43.706:
>   E/ActivityManager(2490):   .app.twlauncher: 2% = 2% user + 0% kernel /
>   faults: 812 minor 01-10 17:55:43.706: E/ActivityManager(2490):
>   mmcqd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

So the problem is undoubtedly (it works if removed) on the while(true) - something that was already working in an AsyncTask in an Activity (without using Services).

What can I do ?

Comment: Hold on a sec, so you're running this service as an async task ? (In a different thread ?)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth, no, I was running (temporarily) the Server Socket on an AsyncTask, before using Services! The obviously problem of that solution is that I can't run the server in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (as with most ANRs) is that you're hogging the main thread. A service by default runs on the main (UI) thread. Since you have a `while(true)`, it's constantly blocking. You should launch a separate thread from your service.

Answer (score 1):

You have some misconceptions about Services Tiago :)
Each service you launch runs by default in the UI thread.
Thread is different from service.
All you need to do is to specify the service so that it runs in a new thread either using java threading or the AsyncTask.

Comment: I solved my problem indeed threading the server :) The problem was in fact, I had no idea that each service runs by default in the UI Thread :)